# How can I toggle the background color of the body of my HTML document, with one button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry, I'm a noob :/. I'm trying to use the toggle function, but I'm open to any other ideas on how to change the background color back and forth with a button as well.

My HTML:

```
    <!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Public Vision</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="backbone" href="backbone.css">
    <link rel="alternative stylesheet" type="text/css" title="alt" href="alt.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body class="style2">
    <div id="header"><div id="header2">Public Vision</div></div>
    <iframe width="640" height="400" 
     src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLX9_I-EOJPdFuOjcI2zkmTck55homHEBE" frameborder="2" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <input type="image" src="off.jpeg " height="3%" width="2%" alt="On" onclick="toggle()">
    </body>
    </html>
```

My JavaScript:

```
    <script>
    function toggle(){
    $('body').toggleClass('style2');
     }

    </script>
```

My css:

```
header { height: 15%; width: 100%; background-color: white; z-align: 2; position: fixed; right:0; top:0; margin-bottom:5px;
 background-color: clear;

 box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #232323;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #232323;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #232323;
}
#header2{height: 15%; width: 100%; position: fixed; color:grey; opacity:   0.6; text-align: center; z-align: 3; font-size: 30px; margin-top: 2.5%;}
iframe {display:block; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 17%;}


body{
background-color:white;
}

 .style2 body{
background-color:grey;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css refers to `.style2 body`, which is looking for a `body` element contained inside of an element with the `.style2` class. If you want to style only `body` when it has the `style2` class, it would be as follows

`body.style2 { background-color: grey; }`

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it, lol of course it was a dumb mistake :p

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to change the background color of `body`, you can try

```
$("body").css("background-color","grey");
```

So your `toggle` function would become

```
<script>
    function toggle(){
        $("body").css("background-color","grey");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do (admittedly not the best solution, but gets the job done)

Html (button)

```
<input type="image" src="off.jpeg " height="3%" width="2%" alt="On" class="bg-toggle">
```

jQuery

```
$('.bg-toggle').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('bgMod')) {
        $(this).toggleClass('bgMod');
        $('body').css('background-color', 'white');
    }else{
        $(this).toggleClass('bgMod');
        $('body').css('background-color', 'grey');
    }
});
```

The biggest pitfall of this is that if you make any changes to `background-color`, in your css they will not have any effect. You could change out `$('body').css('background-color', '???');` for `$('body').toggleClass('style2');`, but make sure to modify your css from this:

```
.style2 body{
    background-color:grey;
}
```

to this:

```
body .style2{
    background-color:grey;
}
```

Otherwise it will be looking for `<element class="style2"><body>`, where it should be looking for a `<body class="style2">`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something simple as this!:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>STACK OVERFLOW TESTS</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = 'button' value = 'CLICK ME FOR CHANGE COLOR!' onClick = 'changeColor()'></input>
    <script>
        function changeColor(){
            var body = document.querySelector('body');

            if(body.style.backgroundColor == 'yellow'){
                body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            }
            else{
                body.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```